# Magento - Magmi - Small_Image not showing in Frontend

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.7, magmi

I'm importing configurable products into Magento using Magmi. Magento CE 1.7

The import works fine, Magmi throws no errors or exceptions or warnings.

The multiple images appear fine in the backend, I can mouse over them, no problems there.

However, when I browse to the product on the website, the "main" image doesn't appear as a "small" image as well. If I manually add the product and images without Magmi, the "main" image does appear as a "small" image as well.

I have attached pictures of my Magmi setup, front-end view problem, and the back-end view.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWgYM.jpg

The CSV file is:

```
    configurable_attributes,media_gallery,sku,name,store,attribute_set,type,categories,product_websites,size,cost,description,options_container,page_layout,price,required_options,short_description,image,small_image,thumbnail,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,status,tax_class_id,visibility,weight,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,,ILUNOV1236S,Black Pocket Out Trackie Shorts,default,Default,simple,,base,Small,,,Block after Info Column,,310,0,,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-01_big.jpg,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-01_big.jpg,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV123601_big.jpg,,,,1,0,1,0,10,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,,ILUNOV1236M,Black Pocket Out Trackie Shorts,default,Default,simple,,base,Medium,,,Block after Info Column,,310,0,,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-01_big.jpg,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-01_big.jpg,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV123601_big.jpg,,,,1,0,1,0,10,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,,ILUNOV1236L,Black Pocket Out Trackie Shorts,default,Default,simple,,base,Large,,,Block after Info Column,,310,0,,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV123601_big.jpg,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV123601_big.jpg,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-01_big.jpg,,,,1,0,1,0,10,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,,ILUNOV1236XL,Black Pocket Out Trackie Shorts,default,Default,simple,,base,X-Large,,,Block after Info Column,,310,0,,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-01_big.jpg,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV123601_big.jpg,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-01_big.jpg,,,,1,0,1,0,10,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,size,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-02_big.jpg;/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-01_big.jpg,ILUNOV1236,Black Pocket Out Trackie Shorts,default,Default,configurable,Pants,base,,,"Back by popular demand. Pocket out trackie shorts are the effortless choice coming in a soft textured material. Details include four over-sized patch pockets in total - two on the front and two on the back - with a I Love Ugly logo patch on the back too. Pair with any t-shirt or shirt in the range and you can't go wrong.<br />",,,310,1,abc,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-01_big.jpg,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-01_big.jpg,/ILUNOV1236/ILUNOV1236-01_big.jpg,,,,1,0,4,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case by 'small image' you are referring to the "`More Images`" on the product view page.

When using Magmi to import you will need to append a '+' to the image field in your csv, so that it doesn't get automatically excluded from being shown in the gallery. You'll be able to see in the Magento admin if the exclude flag is being checked.

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor#Explicit_.E2.80.9Cexclude.E2.80.9D_flag_management.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone else having this problem, there is no solution at this stage.

From the developer himself on Magento forums:

**Hi,
you’re victim of “name aliasing”
I explain. 
The final magento image is stored in a name dependent directory structure under media/catalog
example:
source name : MB1000.jpg will be stored as media/catalog/M/B/MB1000.jpg in magento product image storage 
whatever directory structure is used, using 2 times the same name, magmi will store it as the same target file.
magmi image plugin copies the source image to its final directory/name.
Since you have 2 times same file name from different source directories, magmi identifies the target image (the magento stored one) as existing, thus not modifying anything but the associated label.
This is a specific use case that i could try to adress sometime soon. in the meantime, rename your files differently and all will be imported well.**